# unable to use Collection api methods

Tags: java, collections

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("sdp");// This line isn't working
}
```

Comment: Wrap it in a method/constructor/initialization block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are in the class context, can can just declare and initialize variables here. To call a method on variables you need to do it in the constructor:

```
public class Test {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Test() {
        list.add("sdp");
    }
}
```

Or in a method:

```
public class Test {
    List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();

    private void test() {
        list.add("sdp");
    }
}
```

Beside that use field variables only if necessary.

If you want to initialize a `List` with elements you can use [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("sdp", "test");
```

If you have only one element use [`Collections.singletonList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-) (this returns an immutable list, so you can not add any elements afterwards):

```
List<String> list = Collections.singletonList("sdp");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only have the variable declaration and initialization, method declaration (in case of *Abstract* class) and definition inside the class body (so you can't have *expressions*). If you want to initialize a variable, you can either do it inline or wrap the initialization logic inside an initialization block. Please look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for various ways of initializing class attributes.

Below is one way of initializing class attributes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {


    List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();

    {
       list.add("sdp"); //this will be executed when you create an instance of class `Test`.
    }

}
```